# What are the "basic features" of tokens that allow the Wallet to display them?

Tags: tokens

[Here](https://www.ethereum.org/token) it says:

> Since all tokens implement some basic features in a standard way, this also means that your token will be instantly compatible with the ethereum wallet and any other client or contract that uses the same standards.

Are those standards documented?

Comment: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard , This is the standard interface that all token contract is expected to implement (Juts a standard and if you stick with ERC20 this version is recommended )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this blog post](https://blog.coinbase.com/a-beginners-guide-to-ethereum-tokens-fbd5611fe30b) useful to learn the basic concept of ethereum tokens.

Follow are my understandings regarding ethereum tokens.

> This is because Ethereum tokens are just a specific type of smart
>   contract that live on the Ethereum blockchain.

As I have quoted above basically tokens are also a type of smart contract that sits in the middle of exchanging some service , asset etc. (eg: Golem for computational power) and let that service or asset be traded as its pragmatically defined in that specific type of smart contract. Hence the basic features of a smart  contract are inherited in tokens.

[ERC20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20) documents a set of standard functions(a standard interface) of Ethereum tokens that can be useful and will make it easy (anyway ERC20 tokens are a subset of Ethereum tokens).

> You may hear the Ethereum community refer to ERC20 tokens. The initial
>   ERC20 page “describes standard functions a token contract can
>   implement.” ERC20 is a standard interface for tokens. ERC20 tokens are
>   simply a subset of Ethereum tokens. In order to be fully ERC20
>   compliant the developer needs to incorporate a specific set of
>   functions into their smart contract that at a high level will allow it
>   to perform the following actions:
>
> 1. get the total token supply
> 2. get the account balance
> 3. transfer the token
> 4. approve spending the token
>
> ERC20 allows for seamless interaction with other smart contracts and
>   decentralized applications on the Ethereum blockchain. Tokens that
>   have some but not all of the standard functions are considered to be
>   partially ERC20 compliant and can still be easy for external parties
>   to interact with depending upon which functions are missing.

Hope this helps.